# flutter riverpod leaving screen then come back it doesn't maintain the state

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-futurebuilder

So I have two screens:

-Book_screen to display all the books(click on any book to go to article_screen)

-article_screen to display articles

In article_screen, I can click on article to save it as favorites.
but when I go back to book_screen then come back to article_screen, those favorited articles doesn't show the favorited status(icon red heart).

this is my article screen code:

```
class ArticleENPage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget{

  final String bookName;
  const ArticleENPage({Key? key,@PathParam() required this.bookName,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ArticleENScreen createState()=> ArticleENScreen();
}

class ArticleENScreen extends ConsumerState<ArticleENPage> {
  late Future<List<Code>> codes;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    codes = fetchCodes();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.bookName,style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),backgroundColor: Colors.white,foregroundColor: Colors.black,elevation: 0,),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          //SizedBox(height: 10),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top:10),
              height: 43,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 2),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.32),
                ),
              ),
              child: Consumer(
                builder: (context,ref,_) {
                  return TextField(
                    onChanged: (value) {
                        searchStringController  controller = ref.read(searchStringProvider.notifier);
                        controller.setText(value.toLowerCase());
                    },
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.search,size:18),
                      hintText: "Search Here",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color.fromRGBO(128,128, 128, 1)),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10),
          Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder(
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Code>> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Consumer(
                      builder: (context,ref,child) {
                        final searchString = ref.watch(searchStringProvider);
                        return ListView.separated(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return snapshot.data![index].name
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .contains(searchString) ||
                                snapshot.data![index].description
                                    .toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(searchString)
                                ? Consumer(
                                  builder: (context,ref,child) {
                                    final favlist = ref.watch(FavoriteListController.favoriteListProvider);
                                    print(favlist);
                                    final alreadySaved = favlist.contains(snapshot.data![index]);
                                    return Card(
                                    child:Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                        child:ExpandableNotifier(
                                          child: ScrollOnExpand(
                                            child: ExpandablePanel(
                                                theme: const ExpandableThemeData(hasIcon: true),
                                                header: RichText(text: TextSpan(children: highlight(snapshot.data![index].name, searchString,'title')),),
                                                collapsed: RichText(text: TextSpan(children: highlight(snapshot.data![index].description, searchString,'content')), softWrap: true, maxLines: 3, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,),
                                                expanded: Column(
                                                  children: [
                                                    RichText(text: TextSpan(children: highlight(snapshot.data![index].description, searchString,'content')), softWrap: true ),
                                                    Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                                      children: [
                                                        IconButton(
                                                          icon: Icon(   
                                                            alreadySaved ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                                                            color: alreadySaved ? Colors.red : null,
                                                            semanticLabel: alreadySaved ? 'Remove from saved' : 'Save',
                                                          ),
                                                          onPressed: () {      
                                                              FavoriteListController controller = ref.read(FavoriteListController.favoriteListProvider.notifier);
                                                              if (alreadySaved) {
                                                                controller.toggle(snapshot.data![index]);
                                                              } else {
                                                                controller.toggle(snapshot.data![index]);
                                                              }

                                                          },
                                                        ),
                                                        IconButton(
                                                          icon: const Icon(Icons.content_copy),
                                                          onPressed: () {      
                                                            setState(() {
                                                              Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: snapshot.data![index].name+"\n"+snapshot.data![index].description))
                                                                  .then((value) {
                                                                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: Text('Copied')));
                                                              },);
                                                            });
                                                          },
                                                        ),],),],)),),)));})
                                : Container();
                          },
                          separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return snapshot.data![index].name
                                .toLowerCase()
                                .contains(searchString) ||
                                snapshot.data![index].description
                                    .toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(searchString)
                                ? Divider()
                                : Container();
                          },
                        );
                      }
                    ),
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return const Center(child: Text('Something went wrong :('));
                }
                return const Align(alignment:Alignment.topCenter,child:CircularProgressIndicator());
              },
              future: codes,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

//read from files
  Future<List<Code>> fetchCodes() async {
    final response =
     await rootBundle.loadString('assets/articles.json');

    var CodeJson = json.decode(response)[widget.bookName] as List<dynamic>;
    return CodeJson.map((code) => Code.fromJson(code)).toList();

  }
}
```

I tried using riverpod for provider and save to sharedpreference the list of code that I favorited.

```
    final sharedPrefs =
FutureProvider<SharedPreferences>((_) async => await SharedPreferences.getInstance());

class FavoriteListController extends StateNotifier<List<Code>>{

  FavoriteListController(this.pref) : super(Code.decode(pref?.getString("favcode")??""));

  static final favoriteListProvider = StateNotifierProvider<FavoriteListController, List<Code>>((ref) {
    final pref = ref.watch(sharedPrefs).maybeWhen(
      data: (value) => value,
      orElse: () => null,
    );
    print(pref?.getString("favcode"));
    return FavoriteListController(pref);
  });

  final SharedPreferences? pref;

  void toggle(Code code) {
    if (state.contains(code)) {
      state = state.where((id) => id != code).toList();
    } else {
      state = [...state, code];
    }
    
    final String encodedData = Code.encode(state);
    pref!.setString("favcode", encodedData);
  }

}
```

I am not sure what is the cause of this but I think it might be because of futurebuilder? I am confused to how to solve this issue...
I am stuck in a dead end so any help or advice would be really appreciated

edit 1-
this is my source code in case I have not include all the necessary codes
https://github.com/sopheareachte/LawCode

edit-2
do I need to change "late Future<List> codes;" that fetch all the codes for futurebuilder to riverpod futureprovider too for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is, that you define a static provider inside of your controller class. Try this code:

```dart
final sharedPrefs = FutureProvider<SharedPreferences>((_) async => await SharedPreferences.getInstance());

 final favoriteListProvider = StateNotifierProvider<FavoriteListController, List<Code>>((ref) {
    final pref = ref.watch(sharedPrefs).maybeWhen(
      data: (value) => value,
      orElse: () => null,
    );
    print(pref?.getString("favcode"));
    return FavoriteListController(pref);
  });

class FavoriteListController extends StateNotifier<List<Code>>{

  FavoriteListController(this.pref) : super(Code.decode(pref?.getString("favcode")??""));

  final SharedPreferences? pref;

  void toggle(Code code) {
    if (state.contains(code)) {
      state = state.where((id) => id != code).toList();
    } else {
      state = [...state, code];
    }
    
    final String encodedData = Code.encode(state);
    pref!.setString("favcode", encodedData);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it still doesn't solve the issue. 
I got this exception while running the code:
` An exception was thrown while building StateNotifierProvider<FavoriteListController, List<Code>>#d0e03.

Thrown exception:
An exception was thrown while building _NotifierProvider<FavoriteListController, List<Code>>#3a048.

Thrown exception:
FormatException: Unexpected end of input (at character 1)`

and I notice the print function print two times everytime I click on the icon.

Comment: My bad, it only print once I accidentally left another print function in the code.

Comment: Ok, but you still get the error?

Comment: I tried to debug it and after going through each line, I notice that my .contains function doesn't work when checking the element inside list so I use another function to check if the name of the element is equal to any element name inside the list and it works fine now. Thanks alot for help.